# Injecting Component in Angular 6 Directive got an Error

Tags: angular-directive, angular6

I'm trying to import a component to a directive but got an error instead - this works on angular 5 but not on 6. This is the code:

page-container.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, OnDestroy, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { PageContainerComponent } from '../equity-layout/page-container/page-container.component';

@Directive({
    selector: '[pageContainerContent]'
})
export class PageContainerContentDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(private template: TemplateRef<any>, private container: PageContainerComponent) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.container.addContentTemplate(this.template);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.container.removeContentTemplate();
    }
}
```

This code is not mine but got it from this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-page-layout and trying it on Angular 6 version. Instead I got this error:

[image]

Comment: Hello, you need to change 

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { filter, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

for angular 6 & RxjS 6. like this 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

Comment: My apologies it's a mistake of implementation that caused this error.